# Get complete (ALL, complete) Feed of my profile with API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

i want see all my last activity in Facebook with API. I want make a timeline with all, all, all action that i maked in facebook, like history timeline.
I tried in JS and PHP with feed, but no there are all, dont show things like my last comments, or my last likeds

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/feed');
```

Thanks

Comment: You cant get everything out of facebook in a single query. ;) Its made so for a reason :D

Comment: im using Fql for get all in separated ways... but i don't get all for the moment :(